Deflections and Moments of Slab Computed Numerically
I have the following concrete slab in SAP2000 that I want to solve for:

As you can see the slab in meshed into 36 points and 5 by 5 grids.
I want to solve this slab numerically using MATLAB using the finite difference method. I have found the displacements of this slab - the deflections is SAP2000 are matching that using the FDM.
After obtaining the deflections I thought it would be a rather simple calculation to obtain the bending moments. I have the deflections, and the moments are the second derivative of the deflections. Hence, I am using the second order finite difference:

Where y are the displacements.
Here is the matrix of the displacements in metres for the slab:
dz =

   1.0e-03 *

         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0   -0.1260   -0.1982   -0.1982   -0.1260         0
         0   -0.1936   -0.3059   -0.3059   -0.1936         0
         0   -0.1936   -0.3059   -0.3059   -0.1936         0
         0   -0.1260   -0.1982   -0.1982   -0.1260         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0

I used the flexural rigidity for the slab as:

So I proceed to find the bending moments by:
 for i = 2:5
     for j = 2:5
     BM(i,j) = D*(1*dz(i-1,j) - 2*dz(i,j) + 1*dz(i+1,j))/hx^2 + D*(1*dz(i,j-1) - 2*dz(i,j) + 1*dz(i,j+1))/hy^2
     end
 end 

And I get the following moments:

         0         0         0         0         0
         0    3.1618    4.5668    4.5668    3.1618
         0    4.4487    6.5943    6.5943    4.4487
         0    4.4487    6.5943    6.5943    4.4487
         0    3.1618    4.5668    4.5668    3.1618

These are not matching with SAP2000!
The maximum moment at the centre in the y direction is 4.799 kNm and in the x direction is 3.448 kNm.
Can anyone help me out here, please?

After a quick glance a question pop ups.
On your definition of the matrix BM it seems you are saying
$$
BM(x,y)=D \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x}+ D \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 y}
$$
If I recall correctly, in plates you have
$$
M_x(x,y)=D(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x}+\nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 y})\
M_y(x,y)=D(\nu\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 y})
$$
with $u(x,y)$ the deflection of the plate.
